# Nested for / If loop error in BASH, output not working

Tags: bash

I have a script that starts with a list of filenames in a file.
For each file in the list the script tries to

- look at a line in the file
- if column 2 in that line is `---` then take the value in column 4 from the same line, then use that value to grep the missing `---` value from another, archive file (with same filenameing, but different location and extension)
- then replace `---` with the grepped value.

Therefore the output I would like is the original file, with all instances of `---` changed to their correct value based on a lookup from another column.

This the script I have written to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# process the files in the list
for fname in $mylist ; do
    for line in $fname ; do 
    name=$(echo $fname | awk -F"/" '{print $9}' | sed 's:.ext::g'); #getbasename to help find archive file
    dash=$(awk < "$line" '{print $2}');  #get col2 of the line (may have the "---" missing value")
    loca=$(awk < "$line" '{print $4}');  #col 4 for grepping

        if [$dash -eq "---"]; then   
            ID=$(grep -F -w "$loca" /path/archiveFiles/$name | awk '{print $2}'); #find the missing value in the relevant archive file, using $loca as the lookup key
            fixed=$(awk  -v snpID="$ID" '{OFS="\t"} {print $1,ID, $3, $4}' "$fline");
            echo "$fixed" ;
        else echo "$line" ;
        fi 
    done  >>/path/correctedFiles/$name.ext &

done
wait
```

The script currently gives sterror that says 'Line XX: IDNNNN: command not found'
Line XX doesnt exist in the script (actually it is the last line in the script and is empty)
IDNNNN is one of the missing values I am trying to grep from the archive file.
Can anyone help me resolve this output? Thank you

:edited script to explain the grep a bit better
;edited again example files and error messages:
mylist:

```
> path/dir/file_1_17.03s.07.ext path/dir/file_1_2.51p.12.ext
> path/dir/file_2_112.07.ext path/dir/file_2_155.07.ext
> path/dir/file_13_1.5.12-13.ext
```

Contents of file_1_17.03s.07.ext (all files in same format)

```
>     1 ID45    0   KEY7
>     1 ID46    0   KEY45
>     1 --- 0   KEY501
>     1 ID48    0   KEY6
```

Contents of archive file from which to grep missing data i.e for file file_1_17.03s.07.ext, look in /path/archiveFiles/file_1_17.03s.07.arc

> ```
> X1    ID45    KEY7
> X2    ID46    KEY45
> X3    ID47    KEY501
> X4    ID48    KEY6
> ```

What I am trying to do above is to correct each file in the list, using the KEY column in the relevant archive file so that the contents of file_1_17.03s.07.ext become

> ```
> 1 ID45    0   KEY7
> 1 ID46    0   KEY45
> 1 ID47    0   KEY501
> 1 ID48    0   KEY6
> ```

errors from running my script;

```
> /var/spool/stuff: line 53: ID45: command not found /var/spool/stuff:
> line 53: ID46: command not found (and so on)
```

errors from running with suggested corrections;

> ```
> /var/spool/stuff: line 53: file_1_17.03s.07: command not found
> /var/spool/stuff: line 53: file_1_2.51p.12.: command not found (and so on)
> ```

Comment: `< "$line"` redirects input to the file named `$line`, not from the line itself.

Comment: (1) You can use the `basename` built-in to get the filename from a path. (2) You seem to parsing `ls` output; avoid that. (3) Say `echo ${var} | awk ...` instead.

Comment: I can't figure out what your second `for` loop is doing. The first one already split up `$mylist` into words. There can't be any spaces in `$fname`, so what is that looping over?

Comment: And you're missing the spaces around `[` and `]` in your `if` statement.

Comment: `$name` is set inside the inner loop, but you're using it in the filename redirection for that same loop. That can't work.

Comment: There's so many things wrong with this script, it's impossible to tell what it's trying to do. I think you need to start over, and make sure you understand basic shell syntax. The error message is probably from code that you didn't transcribe into the question.

Comment: The first loop is to read from a list of filenames (in a file, not ls output), the second loop is to take a the file from the list and process it line by line. 
I do know about basename but I thought it might not work because the script reads in a string, which is the filename path. 
Finally there is some code I haven't transcribed in the question but  it's to do with array job submission and works, fine, I've used it many times.

Comment: @jksl: "he second loop is to take a the file from the list and process it line by line" -- nope. The inner loop iterates over every item in the variable `$fname`, which unfortunately contains only one item -- a file name. You need to open the file first and read lines one by one.

Comment: @jksl It's not an issue that the filename is a string. Nearly everything in shell scripts are strings. And input/output are definitely strings.

Comment: @January7, okay, great I'll look into that. I thought it was already opening the files because the error message contained details from within those files, but I can try and correct this.

Comment: You use '-eq' to compare strings. That works only with integers. To compare string use '=='. [Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that *might* work (haven't tested it). Here is what I used to test it.

Creating the test environment:

```
mkdir out
mkdir archive
echo -e "one\ttwo\tthree\tfour\none\t---\tthree\tfour" > test.ext
echo -e "newone\tnewtwo\tnewthree\tfour" > archive/test.arc
rm out/test.ext
```

The following script works.

```
#!/bin/bash

mylist="test.ext"
path_archive="./archive/"
path_out="./out/"

process_line () {
  line=$1
  name=$2
  set -- $line

  if [ "$2" == "---" ] ; then
    ID=$(grep -F -w "$4" ${path_archive}/${name}.arc | awk '{print $2}')
    echo -e "$1\t$ID\t$3\t$4"
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
}

# process the files in the list
for fname in `cat $mylist` ; do
  echo processing $fname

  name=`basename $fname .ext`
  cat $fname | while read line ; do
    process_line "$line" "$name" >> $path_out/$name.ext
  done 
done
```

The `set -- $line` is a bash thing. This sets the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, ...) to whatever arguments were provided to `set --`. With no arguments, `set --` unsets the positional parameters. Consider the following example:

```
:~$ echo $1

:~$ set -- foo
:-$ echo $1
foo
:-$ set -- bar
:-$ echo $1
bar
```

The above `` for fname in `cat $mylist`; do `` will not work if file names in `$mylist` contain spaces. If that is the case and there is exactly one file name in each line, you should do `cat $mylist | while read fname ; do` instead and make sure that `$fname` is always in double quotes (`"$fname"`).

Output:

```
$ cat test.ext
one two three   four
one --- three   four
$ cat out/test.ext
one two three   four
one newtwo  three   four
```

All in all, I would rather use Perl or Python for a task like that. It will be much easier to write and debug.

Comment: Use '==' to compare strings.

Comment: Thank you @January, it's not working still (same IDXXX command not found error) am going to keep searching and playing to fix this, or start again. I have tried with both eq and ==

Comment: Also I have tried to describe the ID=$ line in original post.

Comment: @ahilsend: you are right. jksl: post example files so that we might play with them.

Comment: @jksl: not working, that means what, what is the error message?

Comment: I've tried to imply above the error is ' IDXXX command not found' but I've explained (hopefully) more clearly with example files in the OP. Thank you

Comment: In the meanwhile, I have created a script that seems to work.

Comment: It seems also to work well with your examples, assuming that (i) the ">" in the first file are not meant to be there, and (ii) one has to add the ".arc" extension to the archive file name.

Comment: @January, thank you. When I run the script exactly it processes mylist rather than the files listed within so I'm use cat in the loop (for fname in $(cat $mylist) ; do). That way it's working on some examplefiles. Just trying some text real data before I set it back into the array script

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear from your post that `$mylist` is a *file* containing the filenames.

Comment: @January I was mentioned right at the beginning but no worries, I got there in the end. Can I please ask what the 'set -- $line' part of the script does, I've not come across it before and the man page isn't making it much clearer for me. http://ss64.com/bash/